# How do I prevent the "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" error?

Tags: python

Help, don't have a clue how to do this please help!
Just to say there is a bit of code prior to this I just haven't included it

```
sent = str(input("Please input a sentence:"))
splitsent = sent.lower().split()
deadno = [0]

for count, v in enumerate(splitsent):
if splitsent.count(v) < 2:
    deadno.append(max(deadno) + 1)
else:
    deadno.append(splitsent.index(v) +1)

deadno.remove(0)
print(deadno)
ofile = open ("Task2.txt","a+")
ofile.write("{s!s}\n{d!s}\n").format(s=sent, d=deadno)
ofile.write(sent + "\n" + deadno + "\n")
ofile.close()
```

EDIT:
This is the code now and the traceback I get now is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\.Year 10\Year 10 Computing\A453\Task 2\Test 2.py", line 15, in <module>
    ofile.write("{s!s}\n{d!s}\n").format(s=sent, d=deadno)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Thanks in advance, I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: What are the types of `sent` and `deadno`? you probably need to cast those to `str` so `str(sent)` and `str(deadno)`

Comment: You need to include the two variable assignments.  Also, edit your code -- the indentation is wrong.  And lastly, copy and paste your full traceback to your question.  See @EdChum also.

Comment: @joel goldstick YOU ARE A LEGEND HAVE MY BABIES!!! XP

Comment: What is the output you want for sent = "Hi there"

Comment: 1 2 Wait why???? (dude it was a joke I'm a bloke)

Comment: You should include sample input and desired output in your post.  I'm not sure I understand your comment: 1 2 Wait why????  If that is your desired output you have the d and s values reversed.  You also are trying to print a list of integers, which your code won't do

Answer (score 2):

It is considered good practice to use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) to insert variables in strings.

```
ofile.write("{s}\n{d}\n").format(s=sent, d=deadno))
```

See the [format examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to specify a format for `send` and `deadno`.

If you get the same kind of error, you may force the call of str() on the variables first as suggested in a comment:

```
ofile.write("{s!s}\n{d!s}\n").format(s=sent, d=deadno))
```

`format` is a bit hard to approach (long doc,...) but it has powerful formatting options and it can make your code easier to read and safer.

Also, please edit your question to add variable assignments (the lines where you provide values to `send` and `deadno`) and maybe also print their type and value, just so we know what's in there:

```
for var in [send and deadno]:
    print(type(var))
    print(var)
```

Comment: deadno isn't an int, its a list containing ints.